# GNU assembly. "Movq %rsp, %rax" is assembled into a only 3 byte binary. Not 8 byte.Why?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-architecture, att, machine-code

I use the GNU assembly on 64 bit processor. I assemble the following code

```
movq %rsp,%rax
```

After that, I do a objdump on the binary code.
And I got the following:

```
401000: 48 89 e0                mov    %rsp,%rax
```

I'd thought I would see an 8 byte instruction in binary because my processor is 64 bit, but there is an only 3 byte instruction.

Is it going to be padded into a 8 byte instruction when the CPU decodes the 3 byte one?
For example:

```
48 49 e0  ->  48 49 e0 00 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: Instruction length and word width have no relation.  An x86 instruction is anywhere from 1 to 15 bytes long.

Comment: What makes a processor a 64-bit processor is that it will generally have registers that are 64 bits wide, plus machine code instructions that can manipulate 64-bit quantities in one instruction (like move or copy, add, compare, dereference, etc..).  The width of machine code instructions is an orthogonal issue.